# Java variable to time string conversion

Tags: java, time

If I have 3 variables h, m, s that contains the values 12, 15, 00, how can I convert these variables into time string?

```java
int h=12; int m=15; int s=00; into HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: What is a "time string"? What would it look like for these three variables?

Comment: `java.time.LocalDate`

Comment: @MCEmperor something like this? [LocalTime.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#of-int-int-int-)

Comment: @matt Yes, exactly. (I said `LocalDate`, but of course meant `LocalTime`.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post an example "time string" that you wish to get. And, by the way, have you taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)? Have you visited the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)? Have you read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) By the way, you get a bronze badge after you take the tour and visit the _Help Center_.

Comment: What kind of time do those numbers represent? If an amount of time (like a duration) use the `Duration` class. If a time of day use the `LocalTime` class. In either case search for how to format the object you’ve got, it’s been asked and answered more than once before in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  If it's for an on-screen stop watch, a simple `h + ":" + m + ":" + s;` might be enough to serve your purposes.

If you want the numbers always padded to two digits, maybe `String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s)` is what you're looking for.

If you're trying to keep track of some real time in the world, as MC Emperor pointed out, using the Standard Library's Date API is more appropriate.

Comment: @JoydeepDan: Please use the upvote and accept mechanisms of the site, and you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need prepare your string DateTime:

```
String localTimeStr = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
```

Then you use it with LocalTime:

```
LocalTime localTimeFromStr = LocalTime.parse(localTimeStr);
```

Comment: I don't want the local computer time, I have user given variables, h,m,s that contain some value, and I want to make "HH: mm: ss" format and I want to add another time string with it.

Comment: @JoydeepDan that isn't what a LocalTime is.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options. First:

```
String tm = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s);
```

The resulting string will look like what you want with 0 padded values separated by ":".

You could also create a "LocalTime" object that represents your time.

```
LocalTime tm = LocalTime.of(h, m, s);
```

Now, that represents a time and you can us it as such. You can also format it to a string.

```
String rep = tm.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);
```

For example.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of(12, 3, 0);
System.out.println(lt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));
```

> 12:03:00